# Changing a UIImage in custom tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that is made up of custom tableview cells which contain an imageview.  In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I set the image of each cell.  I want the image to change when the cell is selected, so in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` I get the cell and change the image, no problems there.  However, when I scroll the table (read: table reloads the cells) the new image is no longer present.  Also when the cell is no longer selected I want the image to switch back to the original.

I have tried doing the following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if(cell.isSelected){
cell.imageview.image = [UIImage ImageNamed: @"selected.png"];
}
else
cell.imageview.image = [UIImage ImageNamed: @"not selected.png"];
```

I have also tried using the BOOL values `cell.highlighted` or `cell.selected` to no avail.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Can you also post your code that makes the cell? Because of the reusing mechanism some nasty things can go wrong with cell.isSelected. Another approach is to store the row of the selected cell as a property.

Comment: Show your entire code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a class variable `selectedCellIndexPath` of type `NSIndexPath`. In `didSelectRow...` you set it's value, and in the `cellForRow...` you write:

```
if([selectedCellIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]){
    cell.imageview.image = [UIImage ImageNamed: @"selected.png"];
} else {
    cell.imageview.image = [UIImage ImageNamed: @"not selected.png"];
}
```

**Edit:**

Or you could simply write:

```
if([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForSelectedCell]]){
    cell.imageview.image = [UIImage ImageNamed: @"selected.png"];
} else {
    cell.imageview.image = [UIImage ImageNamed: @"not selected.png"];
}
```

but the first solution is a little more efficient.

Comment: Thanks this did it, I can accept your answer in 3 minutes, and will do

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with the Name of the Images it would be the easiest to change the name at the selected index in the array and reload the table... Like This:

```
myImageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myImageArray addObject:@"name1.jpg"];
[myImageArray addObject:@"name2.jpg"];
// etc..
```

And the in the  cellForRowAtIndexPath Method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

[cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[myImageArray objecAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];

}
```

In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[myImageArray setObject:@"newName.jpg" atIndexedSubscript:indexPath.row];
[tableView reloadData];

}
```